# "No data available" on hover

Tags: carto, layers, infowindow

I have the following map:
https://aressk.cartodb.com/viz/408dd3ea-deea-11e4-9d17-0e9d821ea90d/embed_map

It has two layers.

On the Waypoints layer, I have Hover turned on for the Info Window.
On the SPOT Tracker layer, I have Click turned on for the Info Window.

The hover for the Waypoints works, but the problem is that if I hover over points from the SPOT Tracker layer I get a "No data available" message that I don't want.

If I turn off Hover on the Waypoints layer, the "No data available" will not appear when hovering over a point from the SPOT layer.

Any suggestions on how I can remove the "No data available" message?

Answer (score 1):

That was a bug that was fixed (documented [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/3617)).

From what I can see in your map, that does not happen anymore.